# Mock tests doesn't fail

Tags: node.js, mocking, jestjs, mockingoose

I'm making some tests using mookingose but they always pass even when showing some errors on the console,

This is an example of one of the tests

```
import mockingoose from 'mockingoose';
import { getUserById, insertUser } from '../controller/user';
import User from '../models/users';
import fetch from '../__mocks__/fetchnode';

describe('Test the user mongoose model', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    mockingoose.resetAll();
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  it('should return a valid user with findById user', () => {
    mockingoose(User).toReturn(expectDoc, 'find');

    getUserById('507f191e810c19729de860ea').then(res => {
      expect(res.nickName).toBe(expectDoc.nickName);
    });
  });

  it('should return the user doc with Save user', () => {
    mockingoose(User).toReturn(expectDoc, 'save');

    insertUser(expectDoc).then(res => {
      expect(res.nickName).toBe(expectDoc.nickName);
    });
  });

  it('should return error message with invalid user doc to save user', () => {
    const OnlyAvatar = { avatar: expectDoc.avatar };
    mockingoose(User).toReturn(OnlyAvatar, 'save');

    insertUser(OnlyAvatar).catch(res => {
      expect(res.message).toBe(
        'AAAusers validation failed: name: Path `name` is required., nickName: Path `nickName` is required., email: Path `email` is required., password: Path `password` is required.',
      );
    });
  });
});
```

Right now I'm having errors like these on the console:

```
Expected: "AAAusers validation failed: name: Path `name` is required., nickName: Path `nickName` is required., email: Path `email` is required., password: Path `password` i
s required."
Received: "users validation failed: name: Path `name` is required., nickName: Path `nickName` is required., email: Path `email` is required., password: Path `password` is
 required."
(node:30984) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or
 by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
 PASS  src/routes/user.test.js

Test Suites: 5 passed, 5 total
Tests:       23 passed, 23 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.057s
Ran all test suites matching /src\/routes\/category.test.js|src\/routes\/project.test.js|src\/routes\/task.test.js|src\/routes\/taskSearch.test.js|src\/routes\/user.test.
js/i.
```

The test should fail, but passes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting an `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`.

That means a `Promise` is rejecting but the rejection isn't being handled.

Here is a highly simplified example demonstrating the issue:

```
test('a promise', () => {
  Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    expect(1).toBe(2);  // <= causes UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning
  });
})
```

Since the test isn't waiting for the `Promise` to resolve, the test runs to completion and passes before the `expect` ever has a chance to run.

The `then` callback runs later and the `expect` fails causing the `Promise` to be rejected...but the test has already completed and nothing is handling the rejection.

`Node` detects the unhandled `Promise` rejection and displays the warning.

You always need to [let `Jest` know when your test is asynchronous](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous) and either return the `Promise`:

```
test('a promise', () => {
  return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    expect(1).toBe(2);  // <= fails as expected
  });
})
```

...use an `async` test function and `await` the `Promise`:

```
test('a promise', async () => {
  await Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    expect(1).toBe(2);  // <= fails as expected
  });
})
```

...or use `done`:

```
test('a promise', done => {
  Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    expect(1).toBe(2);  // <= fails as expected
    done();
  });
})
```

In your case the easiest fix is to return the `Promise`:

```
it('should return error message with invalid user doc to save user', () => {
  const OnlyAvatar = { avatar: expectDoc.avatar };
  mockingoose(User).toReturn(OnlyAvatar, 'save');

  return insertUser(OnlyAvatar).catch(res => {  // <= return the Promise
    expect(res.message).toBe(
      'AAAusers validation failed: name: Path `name` is required., nickName: Path `nickName` is required., email: Path `email` is required., password: Path `password` is required.',
    );
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm really thankful!!! I'm just learning programming and web development and I'm really impressed with your explanation, thanks! I hope someday I'll be able to give back the help to the community, sorry if my english is no good.

Comment: you're welcome, glad to hear it was helpful!  @Delm